# We have two coins (a fair and a biased one) with $P(heads)=\frac{2}{3}$. A coin is chosen at random and tossed twice. Find the probability that:

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have two coins (a fair and a biased one) with $P(heads)=\frac{2}{3}$. A coin is chosen at random and tossed twice. Find the probability that:

$1)$ two heads result

$2)$ first toss gives heads and the second, tails.

**MY WORKING**

$1)$ The sample space of random experiment is ${(H,H),(T,T),(T,H),(H,T)}$. Now either the chosen coin is biased or fair hence the $Pr($two heads result$)=$$(\frac{2}{3})^{2}+(\frac{1}{2})^{2}$

$2)$ $Pr($first toss giving heads and second toss giving tails$)=(\frac{1}{3} *\frac{2}{3})+(\frac{1}{2})^{2}$

Is my working correct? If there is a mistake, please guide me. Thanks

Comment: But you have to multiple by $\frac{1}{2}$ in both cases before adding them as that is the probability of choosing one coin vs. the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, yo need to consider the probability of getting two heads ($HH$) conditional of the coin being fair ($F$) and the probability of getting two heads when the coin is not fair ($NF$):
$$P(HH)=P(HH|F)P(F)+P(HH|NF)P(NF)$$
Therefore you'd have $P(HH)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{25}{72}$